Magento 2.4.7-p2 admin dashboard loading all the time can't login
I have installed Magento multiple times, including different versions of 2.4.7-p1 and 2.4.7-p2. But I have been unable to log into the admin control panel, and it keeps loading.
How can i do solve it?
Reference Tutorial(Note that the Elasticsearch version is wrong)
https://www.linuxtuto.com/how-to-install-magento-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-24-04/
I have found the main reason. The default installed Elasticsearch version in this tutorial is 8.15.0. I downgraded the version to Elasticsearch 8.11.0, and the problem was solved.
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.11.0-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-8.11.0-amd64.deb
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

yaml
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
xpack.security.enabled: false
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch

The above content update day 2024.8.24
My server is:
Ubuntu/24.04 LTS,
PHP/8.3.6,
Apache/2.4.58,
Composer version/2.7.7,
elasticsearch/8.11.0.
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://123456.com https://www.123456.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-64anjwo8zEwzG84h9KRhJAmwlH79VidGX9belaIjH+s='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

require.js:168 Uncaught 
Error: Script error for "js/theme"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

Uncaught Error: Script error for "mage/adminhtml/globals"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

Uncaught Error: Script error for "Magento_Catalog/catalog/product"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

require.js:168 Uncaught 
Error: Script error for "mage/backend/bootstrap"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

Uncaught Error: Script error for "Magento_Translation/js/mage-translation-dictionary"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

<script>
    var adminAnalyticsMetadata = {
        "secure_base_url": "http\u003A\u002F\u002Fwww.123456.com\u002F",
        "version": "2.4.7\u002Dp2",
        "product_edition": "Community",
        "user": "a6cf695973a3e9f52563a525b10e263f64eb51e360dc1f9a811cd121e4e8ea0f",
        "mode": "default",
        "store_name_default": "",
        "admin_user_created": "2024\u002D08\u002D19\u002021\u003A08\u003A41",
        "admin_user_logdate": "2024\u002D08\u002D20\u002005\u003A11\u003A13",
        "admin_user_role_name": "Administrators"
    };

    var digitalData = {
        "nonce": "Mjlkb3dxYWl2MmY3NmU5NjFwa285bTU3d3dncHd2d3I\u003D"
    };

    var cspNonce = "Mjlkb3dxYWl2MmY3NmU5NjFwa285bTU3d3dncHd2d3I\u003D";
</script>

The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents cross-site scripting attacks by blocking inline execution of scripts and style sheets.
To solve this, move all inline scripts (e.g. onclick=[JS code]) and styles into external files.
⚠️ Allowing inline execution comes at the risk of script injection via injection of HTML script elements. If you absolutely must, you can allow inline script and styles by:
adding unsafe-inline as a source to the CSP header
adding the hash or nonce of the inline script to your CSP header.

Some resources are blocked because their origin is not listed in your site's Content Security Policy (CSP). Your site's CSP is allowlist-based, so resources must be listed in the allowlist in order to be accessed.
A site's Content Security Policy is set either via an HTTP header (recommended), or via a meta HTML tag.
To fix this issue do one of the following:
(Recommended) If you're using an allowlist for 'script-src', consider switching from an allowlist CSP to a strict CSP, because strict CSPs are more robust against XSS . See how to set a strict CSP .
Or carefully check that all of the blocked resources are trustworthy; if they are, include their sources in the CSP of your site. ⚠️Never add a source you don't trust to your site's CSP. If you don't trust the source, consider hosting resources on your own site instead.



I have solved this problem.
nano .htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

after
bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url https://yoursite.com/

